# Loading records from an XML file into SQLite

Tags: performance, bash, xml, linux, sqlite

I have a script and I need to optimize it to reduce the execution time of this, currently, 6000 lines takes 1 minute and 38 seconds, I would like to reduce the time to take much less and I do not know how to optimize it anymore, I paste the script:

```
#! /bin/bash
function charge_files ()
{
  database="test.db"
  file="Prueba"
  file2="def"
  schema="esquema" #schema sqlite3
  XML="Prueba.xml" #telegramas.xml
  tempschema="tempschema"
    if [ -f $XML ]; then
        echo "============================="
        echo "|        XML CHARGED        |"
        echo "============================="
    else
        echo "============================="
        echo "|      XML NOT CHARGED      |"
        echo "============================="
        exit 1
    fi

}

function extract ()
{
    host=''
    i=0

    while IFS= read -r line; do
        # Find if it is a RecordtStart line
        if [ "$(echo "$line" | grep -c "RecordStart")" -eq 1 ]
        then
            # If host == '', then it is the first host we see.
            # Otherwise, we are changing host, so print an empty line
            if [ "$host" != '' ]
            then
                echo ""
            fi

            # Collect the host information
            connectioname=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d'=' -f2)

            # Collect the ConnectorType information
            connectortype=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $7}' | cut -d";" -f2 | cut -d"=" -f2)

            # Done with this loop in the while, move on to the next
            continue
        fi

        # Find if it is a Telegram line
        if [ "$(echo "$line" | grep -c "Telegram")" -eq 1 ]
        then
            # Collect the Timestamp information
            timestamp=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d"." -f1 | cut -d"=" -f2)

            # Collect the service information
            service=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $3}' | cut -d"=" -f2)

            # Collect the FrameFormat information
            frameformat=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d"=" -f2)

            # Collect the RawData information
            RawDatahost=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $5}' | cut -c 36-39)

            #Collect the RawDate information2
            RawDatahost3=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $5}' | cut -c 50-53)

            # Print the information
            i=$((i + 1))
            echo "$connectioname $connectortype  $timestamp  $service $frameformat $((16#$RawDatahost)) $((16#$RawDatahost3))" >> $file

            # Done with this loop in the while, move on to the next
            continue
        fi

    done <$XML
}
function clean() {
  #Clean the file
  cat $file | tr -d '"' | tr -s " ">> $file2
  cat $file2 | tr ' ' ',' >> definitivo
}
function create_schema(){

  if [ -f "$schema" ]; then
    echo "============================="
    echo "|      LOADED SCHEMA        |"
    echo "============================="
  else
    echo 'CREATE TABLE test (
    KKID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    conection VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    ip VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    time  DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT (strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")),
    service VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    frameformat VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    id_dispositivo VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    id_valor VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
    );' >> $schema
  fi

  if [ -f "$tempschema" ]; then
    echo "============================="
    echo "|    LOADED TEMPSCHEMA      |"
    echo "============================="
  else
    echo 'create table temp (
conection VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
ip VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
time  DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT (strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")),
service VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
frameformat VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
id_dispositivo VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
id_valor VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);
.separator ","
.import ./definitivo temp
.exit' >> $tempschema
  fi

}

function upload() {
  #upload the schema to sqlite3 database
  echo "$(sqlite3 "$database" < "$schema")"

  #Create a temp table with the script
  echo "$(sqlite3 $database < $tempschema)"

  #upload the csv to a temp table
  echo -e ".separator ","\\n.import definitivo temp" | sqlite3 $database

  #make an insert from the temp to the database to get the atribute autoincrement
  echo "$(sqlite3 $database "insert into test (conection, ip, time, service, frameformat, id_dispositivo, id_valor)SELECT * FROM temp;")"

  #delate de table temp
  echo "$(sqlite3 $database "drop table if exists temp;")"

  #remove duplicated fields
  echo "$(sqlite3 $database "DELETE FROM test WHERE oid NOT IN (SELECT min(oid) FROM test GROUP BY conection, ip, time, service, frameformat, id_dispositivo, id_valor)")"

  rm definitivo
  rm "$file"
  rm "$file2"

}
charge_files
extract
clean
create_schema
upload
```

For those who know the script, pass an xml to a very simple csv format, remove the quotes and leave it clean so that later it can be introduced to a sqlite database, the schema has it in the same code, so that it is even simpler and create the necessary files for its execution.

I now attach the xml format, to think that xml can reach more than 7000 lines, but I'll give you an example

```
<CommunicationLog xmlns="http:telegrams">
<RecordStart Timestamp="" Mode="" Host="" ConnectionName="" ConnectionOptions="" ConnectorType="" MediumType="" />
<Telegram Timestamp="" Service="" FrameFormat="" RawData="" />
<Telegram Timestamp="" Service="" FrameFormat="" RawData="" />

<RecordStop Timestamp="" />
<RecordStart Timestamp="" Mode="" Host="" ConnectionName="" ConnectionOptions="" ConnectorType="" MediumType="" />
<Telegram Timestamp="" Service="" FrameFormat="" RawData="" />
<Telegram Timestamp="" Service="" FrameFormat="" RawData="" />
<RecordStop Timestamp="" />
</CommunicationLog>
```

Comment: Have you [profiled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336035/performance-profiling-tools-for-shell-scripts) your shell script in order to know, what to optimize?

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Doing I/O or spawning subshells (or doing just about anything) inside a `while` loop will be slow

By I/O I mean this line with the redirect and append:

```
echo "$connectioname $connectortype $timestamp $service $frameformat \
    $((16#$RawDatahost)) $((16#$RawDatahost3))" >> $file
```

Spawning a lot of subshells for the pipelines would also really slow down your code, as [ceving's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/180871/54092) has shown. If you must set up a pipeline, I suggest you consider the [faster](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127645/performance-differences-between-pipelines-and-process-substitution), Bash-only alternative: process substitution.

So I turned to some `awk` magic one-liner that does both the `extract` and `clean` functions at once:

```
grep -e 'RecordStart' -e 'Telegram' "$XML" | \
    awk -F '"' '{ if( NF > 10 ) { conname = $8; contype = $12 } else \
                printf("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%x,%x\n", \
                conname, contype, $2, $4, $6, substr($8, 36, 4), substr($8, 50, 4)\
                ); }' >> definitivo
```

I don't think I need to explain the `grep` part. `-F` sets the field delimeter to `"`. If `NF`, the number of fields, is greater than 10, we're parsing the `RecordStart` tag so we save the values for `ConnectionName` and `ConnectorType`. If `NF` is not greater than 10, we're parsing the `Telegram` tag so we print the needed columns, including the two previously saved values, and display the last two columns in hex format and the rest as string.

This will be the single change that will make your program fly in high speed lane. That's pretty much it. No command substitutions, almost no pipelines, not even Bash builtins which are still slow, and most importantly, no `while read` loop.

#### Minor notes:

- The traditional way to define a function `foo` is to write it as `foo()`. These days, people write `function foo` without the parentheses. There are minor differences between the two forms, but whatever you choose, don't write `function foo()`.
- Prefer single quotes over double quotes unless you need the expansion.
- For cleanup actions, it's best to write them in a `trap` so they will always be executed unless a `SIGKILL` is received.
- `[[ ]]` is faster and safer (takes care of most of the quoting inside it) than `[ ]`.
- I used a here-document to write the database schemas. There's a variation `<<-` that only works in newer versions of Bash which allows you to indent (with tabs) the input lines and the line containing the delimiter. I opted not to use it because of white space issues in copying and pasting.
- In your `upload` function, I'm not sure what is there to `echo` so I removed them in the revised code below.

### Code

```
#! /bin/bash

database='test.db'
schema='esquema'
XML='Prueba.xml'
tempschema='tempschema'
trap 'rm -f definitivo' EXIT

function charge_files
{
    if [[ -f $XML ]]
    then
        echo '============================='
        echo '|        XML CHARGED        |'
        echo '============================='
    else
        echo '============================='
        echo '|      XML NOT CHARGED      |'
        echo '============================='
        exit 1
    fi
}

function extract
{
    grep -e 'RecordStart' -e 'Telegram' "$XML" | \
        awk -F '"' '{ if( NF > 10 ) { conname = $8; contype = $12 } else \
                    printf("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%x,%x\n", \
                    conname, contype, $2, $4, $6, substr($8, 36, 4), substr($8, 50, 4)\
                    ); }' >> definitivo
}

function create_schema
{
    if [[ -f $schema ]]
    then
        echo '============================='
        echo '|      LOADED SCHEMA        |'
        echo '============================='
    else
        cat >> "$schema" <<'EOF'
CREATE TABLE test (
KKID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
conection VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
ip VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
time  DATETIME NOT NULL,
service VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
frameformat VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
id_dispositivo VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
id_valor VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);
EOF
    fi
    if [[ -f $tempschema ]]
    then
        echo '============================='
        echo '|    LOADED TEMPSCHEMA      |'
        echo '============================='
    else
        cat >> "$tempschema" <<'EOF'
CREATE TABLE temp (
conection VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
ip VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
time  DATETIME NOT NULL,
service VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
frameformat VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
id_dispositivo VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
id_valor VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);
.separator ","
.import ./definitivo temp
.exit
EOF
    fi
}

function upload
{
    # Upload the schema to sqlite3 database
    sqlite3 "$database" < "$schema"

    # Create a temp table with the script
    sqlite3 "$database" < "$tempschema"

    # Upload the csv to a temp table
    sqlite3 "$database" < <(printf '.separator ","\n.import definitivo temp\n')

    # Make an insert from the temp to the database
    # to get the attribute autoincrement
    sqlite3 "$database" "INSERT INTO test (conection, ip, time, service, \
                         frameformat, id_dispositivo, id_valor) SELECT * FROM temp;"

    # Delete the table temp
    sqlite3 "$database" 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp;'

    # Remove duplicate fields
    sqlite3 "$database" "DELETE FROM test WHERE oid NOT IN (\
                         SELECT MIN(oid) FROM test GROUP BY \
                         conection, ip, time, service, \
                         frameformat, id_dispositivo, id_valor);"
}

charge_files
extract
create_schema
upload
```

Comment: I changed this line
 `printf("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%x,%x\n", \ ` --> `printf("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%d,%d\n", \ `
i need it in decimal

Comment: @Nicole Ah yes, that `$((16#$RawDatahost))` thing is new to me. How is the running time now? There's still more optimization you could do with `grep`, but I don't think it matters at this point.

Comment: The time has been reduced from 1m to 38 seconds, not bad, now I just need to add more things to the code, because they ask me even more, but thanks for your help @Gao

Answer (score 3):

This is one of the most inefficient ways to do a sub-string match:

> ```
> "$(echo "$line" | grep -c "RecordStart")" -eq 1
> ```

See yourself.

This creates a small test file:

```
for ((i=0;i<999;i++)); do echo RecordStart; done > data
```

I took just your `while` loop with the `if` statement.

> ```
> while IFS= read -r line; do
>   if [ "$(echo "$line" | grep -c "RecordStart")" -eq 1 ]
>   then
>     echo true
>   fi
> done
> ```

On my system this takes more than 2 seconds:

```
$ time ./slow.sh < data | wc -l
999

real    0m2.311s
user    0m0.036s
sys     0m0.240s
```

The reason is that for each loop one sub-shell gets started for the [command substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst) `$()` and on sub-shell gets started for the pipe and an additional `grep` has to be forked. It is much faster to avoid the three processes per loop by using Bash's built-in sub-string check:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  case $line in
    *RecordStart*)
      echo true
      ;;
  esac
done
```

This is way faster:

```
$ time ./fast.sh < data | wc -l
999

real    0m0.041s
user    0m0.028s
sys     0m0.008s
```

The same applies to your `awk` and `cut` commands. Try to use Bash's [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) instead.

Alternatively you can replace the `extract` function with a Perl implementation. Maybe this helps.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($name, $type);

while (<>)
{
  if (/\bRecordStart\b.*\bConnectionName="([^"]*)".*\bConnectorType="([^"]*)"/) {
    ($name, $type) = ($1, $2);
  }
  if (/\bTelegram\b.*\bTimestamp="([^"]*)".*\bService="([^"]*)".*\bFrameFormat="([^"]*)".*\bRawData="([^"]*)/) {
    print "$name $type $1 $2 $3 ", hex("0x$4"), "\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried what you say and for the moment I have only reduced the time from 7m to 5m @ceving

Comment: @Nicole You have removed all command substitutions executing `awk` and `cut` from the while loop?

Comment: The problem is i cant use perl @ceving