# Optimize and accelerate bash script to transform XML to SQLITE

Tags: bash, csv, xml, sqlite

I have this script in which I read an XML and I pass it to CSV and at the end of the script I transform it into SQLITE

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -f -r rshost rscname rsctype ttstamp tservice tformat trdata trdata2
cat $1 | grep Telegram | sed -e 's/"/ /g' | awk '{ print $9 }' | cut -c27-30 > trdata
cat $1 | grep Telegram | sed -e 's/"/ /g' | awk '{ print $3 }'| cut -c1-19 > ttstamp
a=`cat $1 | grep RecordStart | head -1 | sed -e 's/"/ /g'| awk '{ print $15 }'`
b=`cat $1 | grep RecordStart | head -1 | sed -e 's/"/ /g' | awk '{print $12 }' | sed -e 's/;/ /g' | sed  -e 's/=/ /g' | awk '{print $4 }'`
c=`cat $1 | grep RecordStart | head -1 | sed -e 's/"/ /g' | awk '{print $9,$10 }'`
touch rsctype rshost rscname
kk=`wc -l trdata | awk '{ print $1 }'`
for i in `seq 1 $kk`
do
    echo $a >> rsctype
    echo $b >> rshost
    echo $c >> rscname
done
cat $1 | grep Telegram | sed -e 's/"/ /g' | awk '{ print $5 }' > tservice
cat $1 | grep Telegram | sed -e 's/"/ /g' | awk '{ print $7 }' > tformat
cat $1 | grep Telegram | sed -e 's/"/ /g' | awk '{ print $9 }' | cut -c41-44 > trdata2
cat $1 | grep Telegram | sed -e 's/"/ /g' | awk '{ print $9 }' | cut -c31-34 > grhost

awk -Wposix '{printf("%d\n","0x" $1)}' trdata > trdata3
awk -Wposix '{printf("%d\n","0x" $1)}' trdata2 > trdata4

sed -i "s%^0%0/%g" grhost
cat grhost | cut -c1-3 > grhost2
sed -i "s%.\{4\}%/%g" grhost
pr -mts, grhost2 grhost > grhostfinal
sed -i "s/,//g" grhostfinal
cat grhostfinal | cut -c1-4 > grhostfinal1
cat grhostfinal | cut -c5 > grhostfinal2
awk -Wposix '{printf("%d\n","0x" $1)}' grhostfinal2 > grhostfinal3
pr -mts, grhostfinal1 grhostfinal3 > grhostfinal4
sed -i "s/,//g" grhostfinal4

pr -mts, rshost ttstamp rsctype tservice tformat trdata4 trdata3 rscname grhostfinal4 > conjunto.csv
sed -i "s|^|,|g" conjunto.csv

sqlite3 test2.sqlite "select fecha from testxml4;" > data.csv

cat data.csv | sort | uniq > data2.csv

for k in `cat data2.csv`
do
    grep "$k" conjunto.csv >> quitar
done

diff quitar conjunto.csv | grep ">" | sed 's/^> //g' > diferencia.csv

echo `sqlite3 test2.sqlite < testxml`
python csv2sqlite.py diferencia.csv test2.sqlite testxml4

rm -f -r rshost rscname rsctype ttstamp tservice tformat trdata trdata2 trdata3 trdata4 grhost2 grhost grhostfinal3 grhostfinal1 grhostfinal2 grhostfinal grhostfinal4 a b c data.csv conjunto.csv data2.csv quitar
```

I have this XML (The data is a private)

```
 <CommunicationLog xmlns="http://knx.org/xml/telegrams/01">
  <RecordStart Timestamp="" Mode="" Host="" ConnectionName="" ConnectionOptions="" ConnectorType="" MediumType="" />
  <Telegram Timestamp="" Service="" FrameFormat="" RawData="" />
  <Telegram Timestamp="" Service="" FrameFormat="" RawData="" />
  <RecordStop Timestamp="" />
  <RecordStart Timestamp="" Mode="" Host="" ConnectionName="" ConnectionOptions="" ConnectorType="" MediumType="" />
  <Telegram Timestamp="" Service="" FrameFormat="" RawData="" />
  <Telegram Timestamp="" Service="" FrameFormat="" RawData="" />
  <RecordStop Timestamp="" />
</CommunicationLog>
```

Once analyzed the data, I take them to a CSV and with the Python program csv2sqlite.py

```
python csv2sqlite.py CSVFILE.csv DB.sqlite TABLESQLITE
```

My question is how can I make this script faster and more efficient, since it takes a long time to analyze all the data.

Comment: related: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/180856/37660

Comment: Can you provide the database schema and some dummy data for the XML?  Like the `CREATE TABLE` statement you used and the format of the attributes. An explanation of what each file should contain would also be nice, as currently I'm getting `RawData=` for `tservice` and `Service=` for `ttstamp`, which is super confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take-home message: pipelines in Bash are slow ([compared to process substitution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127645/performance-differences-between-pipelines-and-process-substitution)); loops in Bash are [slow](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice); Bash are slow.

Without a setup script and dummy data to test run it, I don't really understand exactly what your script is trying to achieve at each step, so I can only suggest the following improvements:

### Avoid unnecessary pipelines

- A lot of your code does `cat $1 | grep Telegram | sed -e 's/"/ /g'`, which can be simplified to `sed '/Telegram/!d; s/"/ /g' "$1"`, so you may want to save the result somewhere and extract from it when needed.
- `awk '{ print $9 }' | cut -c27-30` can be combined into `awk '{print substr($9, 27, 4)}'`.
- In the command substitution that gets assigned to `b`, you have `sed -e 's/;/ /g' | sed  -e 's/=/ /g'` which should really just be `sed -e 's/;/ /g' -e 's/=/ /g'` or even better just `sed 's/[;=]/ /g'`. You don't need the `-e` option if you're not combining expressions.
- `` kk=`wc -l trdata | awk '{ print $1 }'` ``: `` kk=`wc -l < trdata` `` can do the job just fine.
- `cat grhostfinal | cut -c1-4 > grhostfinal1` is not as efficient as `cut -c1-4 < grhostfinal > grhostfinal1`
- ```
  sqlite3 test2.sqlite "select fecha from testxml4;" > data.csv

  cat data.csv | sort | uniq > data2.csv
  ```

  is probably best done entirely in SQL:

  ```
  sqlite3 test2.sqlite "SELECT DISTINCT fecha FROM testxml4 ORDER BY fecha;" > data.csv
  ```

### Avoid loops if possible, or optimize for each iteration of the loop

- ```
  for i in `seq 1 $kk`
  do
      echo $a >> rsctype
  done
  ```

  is much slower than

  ```
  printf "$a\n%.0s" `seq 1 $kk` >> rsctype
  ```

  for small `$kk`, and much slower than

  ```
  yes "$a" | head -n "$kk" >> rsctype
  ```

  for large `$kk`. See https://superuser.com/questions/86340/linux-command-to-repeat-a-string-n-times. (Not sure if you actually want to repeat the same strings, but that's what your code does.)
- ```
  for k in `cat data2.csv`
  do
      grep "$k" conjunto.csv >> quitar
  done

  diff quitar conjunto.csv | grep ">" | sed 's/^> //g' > diferencia.csv
  ```

  looks like it could be done with just one `diff`? Maybe (haven't tested it):

  ```
  diff --changed-group-format='%>' --unchanged-group-format='' data2.csv conjunto.csv\
   > diferencia.csv
  ```

### Non-performance-related notes

- You should wrap your cleanup command in a `trap` and put it at the beginning of the script so that it will always be executed unless the program is terminated by a `SIGKILL`:

  ```
  trap 'rm -f \
  rs{host,cname,ctype} \
  ttstamp tservice tformat trdata{,2,3,4} \
  grhost{,2,final{,{1..4}}} \
  data{,2}.csv conjunto.csv \
  {a..c} quitar' \
  'EXIT'
  ```
- Please don't `rm -r` if you're not deleting directories. This is a dangerous command if you're not careful. I used brace expansion to shorten the list of input files I need to type, but I'm not sure if you really need to create that many temporary files.
- You don't need to `touch` the files. Redirection will create the files if they don't exist.

I can probably offer more suggestions if I could try out the script. I'll add to this answer if I think of anything, but this should be enough for now.